# How to make animation to Ngx-Bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: angular, animation, css-animations, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I am using `ngx-bootstrap` for my project especially Dropdown.

I want to add some animations to here, but don't know how to do that.
Is there any recommended way to add animation to `ngx-bootstrap/dropdown`?